# OSX - working with multiple tableviews - how to check cell out of bounds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nstableview

I'm getting an exception in `objectValueForTableColumn` when selecting a row in an `NSTableView`, that is exceeding the `numberOfRowsInTableView`.

I think this may be caused by using single methods to control multiple table views, but I don't know what to do instead.

The `numberOfRowsInTableView` looks like this:

```
    switch (tableView.tag) {
        case 0:
            return [itemMutableArray count];
            break;

        case 1:
            return [categoryMutableArray count];
            break;

        case 2:
            return [peopleMutableArray count];
            break;

...
```

and the `objectValueForTableColumn` method looks like this:

```
if (tableView.tag == 0) {
    currentItem = [itemMutableArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *itemName = [currentItem valueForKey:@"title"];
    return itemName;        
}

if (tableView.tag == 1) {
    currentCategory  = [categoryMutableArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *catName = [currentCategory valueForKey:@"name"];
    return catName;
}
```

If I click out of bounds first, no problem. But when I click a row, then click out of bounds, I get the following logs:

```
2013-06-18 13:40:16.169 TestApp[43953:303] -[MainWindowController tableViewSelectionDidChange:]
2013-06-18 13:40:16.169 TestApp[43953:303] Items Table View
2013-06-18 13:40:17.641 TestApp[43953:303] -[MainWindowController tableViewSelectionDidChange:]
2013-06-18 13:40:17.641 TestApp[43953:303] Items Table View
2013-06-18 13:40:17.642 TestApp[43953:303] *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]
2013-06-18 13:40:17.643 TestApp[43953:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8574e8ce __exceptionPreprocess + 174
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8b4e7f51 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff856ea615 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 245
    3   TestApp                      0x0000000100007508 -[MainWindowController tableViewSelectionDidChange:] + 760
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff856ffa63 _CFXNotificationPost + 3203
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d25c24a -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f7fdfc5 -[NSTableView _sendSelectionChangedNotificationForRows:columns:] + 177
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f7e3f2a -[NSTableView _enableSelectionPostingAndPost] + 406
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8fbbc7e0 -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 5588
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f780918 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 11303
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f77af48 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2021
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f69c599 -[NSApplication run] + 646
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f646563 NSApplicationMain + 940
    13  TestApp                      0x0000000100015982 main + 34
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8f28e60d start + 1
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I've added a log to my question.

Comment: Sorry, I have to listen to messages to understand, and I missed the point. I will do as you suggest and report back.

Comment: Unless people think this is wrong, I will rethink my architecture and create separate ViewControllers for each view. Otherwise, I am boxing myself in too much. @Monolo, your comment directing me to the correct method was very helpful. If you wish to write your suggestion as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Took your suggestion and posted it as an answer. I'll also delete my part of comments here to help clean up the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to go to the debugger and set a breakpoint for exceptions, then take a look at the variables before the app dies.

To set a breakpoint for exceptions, switch to debugger view and click the "+" sign in the lower left-hand corner. This will give you a menu with the choice of an Exception breakpoint or a symbolic one.

The crash log on the other hand provides different information compared to the debugger. But even so, if you read the stack trace you can see that the crash happens in `tableViewSelectionDidChange:` so maybe it would be more relevant to look there first.